# How to properly select these elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div id="main-content">
  <div>
    <div>target me
         <div>don't target me</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>target me too
         <div>don't target me</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried this:

```
#main-content div>div {

}
```

But this ALSO targets the divs saying "don't target me" I wish not to target those divs.

Of course we can use Id's or classes, but the point is to declare a general rule for all.

Please advice.

Comment: `#main-content > div > div` ? http://jsfiddle.net/zXaLU/

Comment: ARRGHHTTT!!!!! :ppp missed the > grr!!  - I will kill myself. :p

Comment: @TimMedora is right. Here's why: `#main-content div` gets all divs under `#main-content`, including the 'target me' ones, which make the next `>div` return the 'don't target me' divs.

Comment: I guess it depends if you want it to be compatible with IE7/6/5.

Comment: @MattK I believe the child sign is well supported on IE7 no ? I'm only targeting ie7 and up btw.

Comment: @MEM: Descendant is space, child is `>`, and yes it's supported on IE7.

Comment: @BoltClock: [Sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector) says it's buggy in IE7 as well as other references. Haven't had the chance to test it though.

Comment: @Matt K: Yes, but if you read the bugs there, you'll find that the odds of those bugs ever happening in the wild is almost zero. IE7 handles it almost flawlessly otherwise - there's just a bunch of syntactic edge cases that should seldom if ever happen in real-world code anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock: Not necessarily. A quick search brings up a lot of issues with IE7. Not using standards mode, conflicts with plugins like selectivizr and respond.js. The asnwer is correct, was just saying to watch out for some issues that might arise.

Comment: @Matt K: Yeah, I see your point there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just refine the selector a bit to enforce the hierarchy: `#main-content > div > div`

http://jsfiddle.net/zXaLU/

As a note, when using structural selectors it's nice to reference non-generic tags.

Example: `#main-content > NAV > UL` is more meaningful than `#main-content > DIV > DIV`

Comment: What about something like `font-weight: bold;` See http://jsfiddle.net/zXaLU/1/ ?

Comment: That's just normal CSS inheritance. If you wanted a different behavior on the child elements, you would define a different selector or class to override the behavior of the parent.

Comment: I have no semantic reasons to have other element then divs here, so I must have divs. But that indeed a good tip. :) And for the sake of others, I must say that this is the far I get: div>div :) I swear to never do: `#main-content>div>div>div>div` :p

Comment: haha, yeah the more levels you select the harder it is to maintain, and performance can suffer (although `>`is a fairly easy selector for a browser to handle).

Answer (score 1):

If you want styles only to apply to the outer of the two divs, you need to use two style definitions. The first sets the style for the div targeted and the second for the inner div not to be targeted:

```
#main-content div>div {
  /* set some styles */
}
#main-content div>div>div {
  /* reset the styles defined before */
}
```

In general the inner div (not targeted) inherits all the styles of its parent div, so in order to nullify that effect, you have to explicitly reset all those styles again.

**EDIT**

After all comments: If "targeting" does not include usual CSS inheritance, Tim Medora's answer is more suitable. My answer tried to account for inheritance as well.

Comment: No need. See Tim Medora's answer.

Comment: @BoltClock depends on the style set. See http://jsfiddle.net/zXaLU/1/ for a counter example.

Comment: Depends on whether the OP is interested in preventing inheritance... whether a style is inherited or not doesn't have anything to do with selecting the parent.

Comment: @Sirko If we declare values two times, one for set, and another for unset, why not just set it, and if and only if some styles get inherit overwrite them? What do you think ? It makes sense to me I believe.

Comment: @Mem The same approach. It just depends on where you need that style and where you don't.

Answer (score 0):

> How [dooes one] properly select [the specified] elements?

The "proper" way would be to give the items you want to select a class that is indicative of their status:

```
<div id="main-content">
  <div>
    <div class="someclass">target me
         <div>don't target me</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="someclass">target me too
         <div>don't target me</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

...and then you can simply use the `class` selector:

```
.someclass {
    ...styles...
}
```

But if you're unable to modify the markup, you can still use the [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) chain:

```
#main-content > div > div {
    ...styles...
}
```